# mkv video doesn't play in my nuxt project (webpage)

Tags: html, video, vue.js, nuxt.js, mkv

**I am new to Vue.js / Nuxt / Webpack**

The Problem: My web page displays a video. This works fine for normal formats like .mp4
but I have tried displaying a .mkv video, which produces the error:

> Module parse failed: Unexpected character '->' (1:0) You may need an
>   appropriate loader to handle this file type. (Source code omitted for
>   this binary file)

If I open the .mkv file in chrome, the video plays normally. So, I tried using the code from the browser in my project:

```
<video controls="" autoplay="" name="media"><source src="file:///F:/test/video.mkv" type="video/webm"></video>
```

And this works for normal web pages, but not for my nuxt/vue project. Any idea where I can configure nuxt to display this type of format?

I read somewhere that I can set this up in the nuxt.config.js or webpack.config.js but I don't know what to do there.

I tried to define values in the **build** part of the nuxt.config.js but it doesn't work (honestly I don't really know what I am doing here, just gave it a shot):

```
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.(mkv)$/,
      loader: 'file-loader',
      query: {
        limit: 100
      }
    }
  ]
```

And I just want this to work in Chrome, but the real problem seems to be the nuxt config.

Comment: Place video.mkv under static folder inside your nuxt project. Then change src attribute in source element as src="/video.mkv". let me know if it works.

Comment: if you are opening the mkv as file:/// then you also have to have opened the web page as file:/// and paths have to match. also mkv isn't a native supported container in Chrome so might not play back, finally, if it will play back you'd need an appropriate mime type defined so the server knows how to handle it

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem.
And I found the following things.
`npm run dev` : autoplay works.
`npm run build && npm run start` : autoplay doesn't work.

my `package.json` :

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon server/index.js --watch server",
  "build": "nuxt build",
  "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production nodemon server/index.js --watch server"
}
```

So I guess the problem cause some process with `NODE_ENV=production` .